# Kotlin - Reading the least significant bit (Steganography)

Tags: kotlin

I am creating a program that can read the least significant bit of a image file using Kotlin. I have a function that reads the bytes in a file, but I am unsure how to actully print the bytes in the function consumeArray.

My goal is to print the least significant bits of a image.

```
override fun run() {
    val buff = ByteArray(1230)
    File("src\\main\\kotlin\\day01_least_significant_bit_steganography\\eksempel_bakgrunnsbilde.png").inputStream().buffered().use { input ->
        while(true) {
            val sz = input.read(buff)
            if (sz <= 0) break

            ///at that point we have a sz bytes in the buff to process
            consumeArray(buff, 0, sz)
        }
    }
} // run

private fun consumeArray(buff: ByteArray, i: Int, sz: Int) {
    println("??")
} // consumeArray
```

Comment: Do you mean least significant bit of the first byte in the array? Of the last one? Of byte pointed by `i`? Big or little endian? Generally speaking, you can get the least significant bit of any byte by simple: `byte and 0x1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.4+ you can get the least significant bit of any byte with [.takeLowestOneBit()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-lowest-one-bit.html) method.

It may happen that it's equal to zero, so you need to iterate byteArray until any non-zero least significant bit is met (I believe this is what was meant under "least significant bit of byteArray"):

```kotlin
var lowestBit: Byte = 0
for (index in sz - 1 downTo 0) {
    val currentLowestBit = buff[index].takeLowestOneBit()
    if (currentLowestBit != 0.toByte()) {
        lowestBit = currentLowestBit
        break
    }
}
```

Note that it will print the least significant bit of your buffer, not the whole image (if it's bigger than the buffer)